# When zooming in on an image, how do I get the overflow to not go over the images next to it?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, zooming

I have 2 questions.

1) When the image is zoomed in how do I get the overflow of the image to go behind the image next to it?

I have tried `overflow: hidden;` but that doesn't work.

2) How do I get the image to snap back to its original form when not hovered over anymore?

I don't know any way to do this and I have looked every where.

```css
.main{
  font-size: 0px;
}

.pic{
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 0px;
}

.pic img {
    -webkit-transition: all 2s ease-in-out; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transition: all 2s ease-in-out; /* Firefox */
    -ms-transition: all 2s ease-in-out; /* IE 9 */
    -o-transition: all 2s ease-in-out; /* Opera */
    transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
}

.pic:hover img {
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.05); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transform:scale(1.05); /* Firefox */
    -ms-transform:scale(1.05); /* IE 9 */
    -o-transform:scale(1.05); /* Opera */
     transform:scale(1.05);
}
```

```html
  <div class="main">
    <div class="pic">
      <a href=""><img src="img/1.png" alt="food" height="337.2" width="337.2"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="pic">
      <a href=""><img src="img/2.jpg" alt="food" height="337.2" width="337.2"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="pic">
      <a href=""><img src="img/3.jpg" alt="food" height="337.2" width="337.2"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="pic">
      <a href=""><img src="img/4.jpg" alt="food" height="337.2" width="337.2"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="pic">
      <a href=""><img src="img/5.jpg" alt="food" height="337.2" width="337.2"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="pic">
      <a href=""><img src="img/6.jpg" alt="food" height="337.2" width="337.2"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="pic">
      <a href=""><img src="img/7.jpg" alt="food" height="337.2" width="337.2"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="pic">
      <a href=""><img src="img/8.jpg" alt="food" height="337.2" width="337.2"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="pic">
      <a href=""><img src="img/9.jpg" alt="food" height="337.2" width="337.2"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="pic">
      <a href=""><img src="img/10.jpg" alt="food" height="337.2" width="337.2"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="pic">
      <a href=""><img src="img/11.jpg" alt="food" height="337.2" width="337.2"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="pic">
      <a href=""><img src="img/12.jpg" alt="food" height="337.2" width="337.2"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="pic">
      <a href=""><img src="img/13.jpg" alt="food" height="337.2" width="337.2"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="pic">
      <a href=""><img src="img/14.jpg" alt="food" height="337.2" width="337.2"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="pic">
      <a href=""><img src="img/15.jpg" alt="food" height="337.2" width="337.2"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="pic">
      <a href=""><img src="img/16.jpg" alt="food" height="337.2" width="337.2"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the styles that you have under ".pic img" into ".pic:hover img" because you only want these effects to occur while you are hovering. I also added a z-index to the hovered image to make it move below the other ones. Lastly, I removed some of the images and added borders just for clarity and conciseness.
https://jsfiddle.net/n5m70m2m/

HTML

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="pic">
      <a href=""><img src="http://placehold.it/337X337" alt="food" height="337.2" width="337.2"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="pic">
      <a href=""><img src="http://placehold.it/337X337" alt="food" height="337.2" width="337.2"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="pic">
      <a href=""><img src="http://placehold.it/337X337" alt="food" height="337.2" width="337.2"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="pic">
      <a href=""><img src="http://placehold.it/337X337" alt="food" height="337.2" width="337.2"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="pic">
      <a href=""><img src="http://placehold.it/337X337" alt="food" height="337.2" width="337.2"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="pic">
      <a href=""><img src="http://placehold.it/337X337" alt="food" height="337.2" width="337.2"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="pic">
      <a href=""><img src="http://placehold.it/337X337" alt="food" height="337.2" width="337.2"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="pic">
      <a href=""><img src="http://placehold.it/337X337" alt="food" height="337.2" width="337.2"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="pic">
      <a href=""><img src="http://placehold.it/337X337" alt="food" height="337.2" width="337.2"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="pic">
      <a href=""><img src="http://placehold.it/337X337" alt="food" height="337.2" width="337.2"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="pic">
      <a href=""><img src="http://placehold.it/337X337" alt="food" height="337.2" width="337.2"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="pic">
      <a href=""><img src="http://placehold.it/337X337" alt="food" height="337.2" width="337.2"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
.main{
  font-size: 0px;
}

img {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.pic{
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 0px;
}

.pic:hover img {
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.05); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transform:scale(1.05); /* Firefox */
    -ms-transform:scale(1.05); /* IE 9 */
    -o-transform:scale(1.05); /* Opera */
     transform:scale(1.05);
     position: relative;
     z-index: -1;
     transition: all 2s ease-in;
     -webkit-transition: all 2s ease-in-out; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transition: all 2s ease-in-out; /* Firefox */
    -ms-transition: all 2s ease-in-out; /* IE 9 */
    -o-transition: all 2s ease-in-out; /* Opera */
}
```